# Parse second number combination of string with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am sure this is simple, but I can't figure it out.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
 control366NameJ04
```

I want to parse the second number '04' from that string.

I have tried using regex but I am only able to extract the first number '366'.

```
 Regex.Match(control,@"\d+");
```

How can I parse the second number out of the string with regex. And if I can't with regex can I use something else within C#?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all matches in the string, then you can get any position you want on the returned `Match` array

`var matches = Regex.Matches(control, @"\d+");`

Answer (score 4):

```
var d = Regex.Matches("control366NameJ04", @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Last().Value;
```

Comment: In case it complains `... does not contain a definition for 'Cast'...`, it requires `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the second number will be the end of the string, you can use this regex:

```
\d+$
```

It will match one or more digits that immediately precede the end of the string.